# How to create BigInteger of 256 bits with all bits set

Tags: java, biginteger

How can I create a BigInteger with 256 bits that are all set ? I've already tried the following:

```
BigInteger.valueOf(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL)
```

But it doesn't give me the desired result:

```
int bitCount = b.bitCount();// 0
int bitLength = b.bitLength();// 0
```

What I basically need is a number containing 256 bits which are all set.

Tnx!

Comment: Have you tried using `Long.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That would be only 63 1-bits, not 256.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(256).subtract(BigInteger.ONE)
```

It calculates first 2^256, which is in binary a one followed by 256 zeroes, and then subtracts one which leaves just 256 ones.

Comment: For anyone arriving here looking for a C# answer (like I did), use `(BigInteger.One << 256) - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger with 256 1-bits:

```
byte[] b = new byte[256 / 8 + 1]; // 256 bits + 1 byte
Arrays.fill(b, (byte) 0xFF);      // with all 1's
b[0] = 0; // except first 8 bits 0's, so value is positive
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(b);
System.out.println(bi);
System.out.println("bitCount = " + bi.bitCount());
System.out.println("bitLength = " + bi.bitLength());
```

*Output*

```
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935
bitCount = 256
bitLength = 256
```

A bit more cumbersome than [answer by @Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48993815/5221149), but likely faster, though that probably doesn't matter.